# Is there a way to scrape the download file from a site that isn't just the HTML link?

Tags: file, screen-scraping, download

So I am individually going through each link to download the file for photoshop presets, it is a little tiring to say the least. I've been researching ways to actually scrape the file and not just the `HTML` link or some way to take all the files at once from a page, but I've not had any luck. I am not versed in `python` so it doesn't make any sense to me, and the programs I have installed to do this for me aren't downloading what I am looking for.

I've tried chrome extensions, web scraping software, but it has not worked the way I am looking for.

https://www.brusheezy.com/brushes/22482-star-glow-brushes

this is just one of the links on one page

I expect to find something that will actually download the zip file from the link on the page.

Comment: What I am asking for is being able to go onto the brusheezy website, go to an uploader's page, and instead of clicking on each image that takes me to the download button, I want to hit one button or type in some type of code that I understand and it scrapes the download file from all the of a href tags in the code. Each time I go to download a file it downloads in a zip file which is fine, it's just a little tiring going through each one.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I have not gotten this to work yet but thought the approach might be worth considering. I'll try to come back and either improve or delete it.

You might be able to do something along these lines in the browser's dev tools. You'll have to disable your popup blocker for this. This doesn't quite work for me because the download button started throwing up an account signup dialog. I suspect they might do this after some number of downloads, but you might have better luck if you have an account and are logged in.

Navigate to an uploader's page, open the browser's developer tools, paste in the code below and hit enter.

```
function go () {
    // get all the links from the grid on the current page
    const hrefs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.ez-resource-grid a[href]')).map(a => a.href);

    // start the loading
    next(hrefs);
}

function next ([current, ...remaining]) {
    // open a new tab/window with the current href;
    const w = window.open(current, '_blank');

    // function to find the download button and "click" it.
    function triggerDownload () {
        try {
            w.querySelector('#download-button').click();
        }
        catch (e) {
            // something went wrong.
        }

        // if we haven't consumed all the links yet, start the next one.
        if (remaining.length) {
            next(remaining);

            // I tried adding a delay here thinking the account signup dialog
            // might be triggered by too many rapid requests, but it didn't
            // seem to matter.
            // setTimeout(() => next(remaining), 6000);
        }
    }

    // give the page a few seconds to load before attempting
    // to trigger the download. This should be replaced with
    // a ready event listener instead of a fixed delay, something
    // like:
    // w.document.addEventListener('readystatechange', triggerDownload)
    // but i'm tired and my first attempt didn't appear to work so i'm
    // throwing in this static delay hack instead.
    setTimeout(triggerDownload, 5000);
}

// kick it off
go();
```

Comment: Unfortunately all it did was open the page where the download button is, but thank you for seriously trying, I really appreciate it. It is on the right track though.

Comment: The resource https://static.brusheezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/001/325/large_2x/set2-splat-spraycan-brushes.gif was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
download_ad_modal-98deffa955a0abf20ddfd62b2b292648.js:4 Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/zip: "https://static.brusheezy.com/system/protected/files/000/001/325/Set2_Splat_SprayCan_brushes_by_qnerve_abr.zip?md5=Cwo3meyoXjHc07PyYLH0Og&expires=1559238596".

Comment: This is what I get when I download one of the brushes from the site, I don't know if it will help you or not?